# How to use only a part of an existing colormap?

Tags: matlab, visualization, data-visualization, matlab-figure, colormap

I am using colormap to visualize some data:

```
DataToPlot = pcolor(myData);
set(DataToPlot,'edgecolor','none'); %to remove grid
colormap(flipud(spring));
caxis([-4 4]);
colorbar;
```

At the moment the colour associated with the value `-4` is yellow, and the colour associated with `+4` is bright pink. I would like to modify this scale and have as colour associated with `-4` what is now the colour for `0` (which is a light pink), and leaving the colour associated with `+4` as the bright pink.

How can I do this?

Comment: `caxis` is maybe what you need. Otherwise take the colormap,crop it where you want, and then set that one as the colormap

Comment: To elaborate on Ander's comment - let's say you want only the red->green part of the HSV colormap, you can do something like `cm = hsv(300); cm = cm(1:100,:); colormap(cm);`

Comment: @Dev-iL, thanks, very helpful. Just a question, sorry if basics, but how do you know the values (in your example 300 and 1:100) to choose? Is there any index for each colormap? Thank you.

Comment: I just like having a visually smooth colormap, so I usually use at least 100 colors. Just looking at the colormap it seemed like approximately 1/3 to me - hence, to get a colormap that is 100 entries long, I needed to create a 300-long colormap and get the first third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the following example:

```
figure(); imagesc(magic(4)-8); colorbar;
% Flipped "spring" colormap:
cm = flipud(spring); colormap(cm);
```

Now we have:

[image: Flipped <code>spring</code>]

If we want only a **subset** of the colormap (e.g. yellow to pink) we can take a subset of the rows of the array returned by `spring`:

```
cm = flipud(spring(200)); colormap(cm(1:100,:));
```

where `200` is the resolution of the colormap we want to get, and `100` is approximately the position of the map where we want to cut, yielding:

[image: First half of the flipped <code>spring</code>]

If we want to rescale the colormap (or in other words change the mapping of data to colors such that the min/max value does not correspond to the bottom/top color), we can use [`caxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) function to set different limits for the colormap. For example:

```
cm = flipud(spring); colormap(cm); caxis([-7 24]);
```

yields the same data coloring using the complete colormap:

[image: Rescaled colormap]

Bonus: don't forget you can also combine different colormaps:

```
cm = [flipud(bone(50)); copper(50)]; colormap(cm);
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very comprehensive answer. Thank you! Do you how many colors does Matlab actually uses to create the colormap? For example, if we have a colormap from -4 to +4, does Matlab uses 800 colors (i.e., 100 colors for each unit)? Jut curiosity.

Comment: Well, it's easy to check... just type `cm = spring` and look at the size of the output. The result isn't exactly what you expected :)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried the last code you showed, which is very nice. But if I do:  `mySpring = spring(400); mySpring = mySpring(1:200,:); colormap(flipud(mySpring));

myBone = bone(400); myBone = myBone(1:200,:); colormap(myBone);

cm = [myBone(50);flipud(mySpring(50))]; colormap(cm);` I get this error: `Error using colormap (line 93)
Colormap must have 3 columns: [R,G,B].` Do you know why?

Comment: @dede you can't do that, because the functions `spring` and `bone` are not simple 2D arrays, but rather perform some computation. You can open any one of them to see how it works. If you want to fix your example, make sure you use `mySpring(1:50,:)` and not just `mySpring(50)`. `spring(50)` returns a 50x3 array, whereas `mySpring(50)` is a scalar.